# Getting empty response when returning JSON data using jsonModel on Doctrine result - Special characters encoding issue

Tags: php, json, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am having problems getting ZF2 jsonModel to return multi result from doctrine query.
The issue appears only when I try to return the array result and not when returning individual items
my code is as below:

```
public function mosquesAction() {

    $em = $this
            ->getServiceLocator()
            ->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
    $dql = "select m.name from \Application\Entity\Mosque m ";
    $result = $em->createQuery($dql)->getResult();

    return new JsonModel($result);   
}
```

the Mosque Entity is:

```
namespace Application\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/** @ORM\Entity */
class Mosque {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
private $name;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
private $address;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
private $email;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
private $website;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
private $phone;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
private $mobile;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
private $fax;

/** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
private $coordinates;

/** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Canton", inversedBy="mosques") */
private $canton;

public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
}

}
```

when I change the return value to

```
return new JsonModel($result[0])
```

I get the result

> {"name":"IDTV - Mimar Sinan Camii"}

## EDIT:

I think I found the origin of the issue, there is no problem with code I posted but it appears that JsonModel can't handle special characters like in

> Islamische König Faysal Stiftung

So my question now is, how to encode these characters in JsonModel on php5.3?

Thank you in advance and sorry for my poor English

Comment: What result do you get? Are there any error messages? UTF-8 encoding shouldn't cause any problem.

Comment: empty page when trying to return the unicode data, I tried _return new JsonModel(array('Föderation Islamischer Gemeinschaften LU'));_ get ["F\u00f6deration Islamischer Gemeinschaften LU"] so maybe the issue is related to database?

Comment: You mean a completely empty string? No error messages in the log?

Comment: here is an example of var_dump(result[1])
Array
(
    [id] => 197
    [name] => Föderation Islamischer Gemeinschaften LU
    [address] => Hauptstrasse 58
    [email] => 
    [website] => 
    [phone] => 041 260 90 98
    [mobile] => 
    [fax] => 
    [coordinates] => 47.0666986,8.2812254
)
the same return empty result with JsonModel "empty string"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After playing with different options I got to the result that the issue resides in doctrine connection to MySQL database, So I changed my database collation to _utf8_general_i_ and added some parameters to the driver params:

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'driverOptions' => array(
     1002 => 'SET NAMES utf8'
)
```

now I get the result I was expecting

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Föderation Islamischer Gemeinschaften LU",
    "address": "Hauptstrasse 58",
    "email": "",
    "website": "",
    "phone": "041 260 90 98",
    "mobile": "",
    "fax": "",
    "coordinates": "47.0666986,8.2812254"
}
```